# Weird SettingWithCopyWarning in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read lot of posts and information about that error in pandas. I try to write a code in different way, but nothing helps and it's still unclear to me.

I have a dataframe - df1 with three cols:

```
SampleIdInt, Username, Signature
```

When I try to add a column filled '1' to df I got an SettingWithCopyWarning. 
Code:

```
df1['PolName'] = 1
```

In my another script that code didn't throw error, so why in this case i got it? I have just delared dataframe and dictionary.

Next, when I try to translate values by a dictionary it again throw a error. Code:

```
df1.loc[:,'PolName'] = df1['SampleIdInt'].apply(lambda y:slownik[y] if y in slownik.keys() else 'None')
```

I tried with loc, iloc, with different code syntax. Everytime I gor an error. What is weird? Somethimes I got an error and code modified a df anyway, sometimes I got an error, and df stay unchaged - I don't change anything in that code.

Can someone explain me what is a problem, exactly on above example?

**Important parts of code. Could be useful:**

```
baza = pd.read_csv('Zeszyt1.csv', sep = ';')
snps = pd.read_csv('snps.csv', header = None, low_memory = False, sep = ',')

vals = snps.loc[snps.duplicated(['SampleIdInt',5]), 'SampleIdInt'].unique()

mask = snps['SampleIdInt'].isin(vals)

df1 = snps[~mask]
```

Comment: yes, because `df1` is a copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is:

```
df1['PolName'] = df1['SampleIdInt'].map(slownik).fillna('None')
```

Also you can add [copy()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) to `df1` assignment:

```
df1 = snps[~mask].copy()
```

Comment: df1.copy() works, but why? Can u explain me? Everytime when I processing df I shoudl copy it? And If I copy df the RAM usage wil be 2x ?